# Beamer, TOC other language

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, babel

In this code, I would like to have that the words out of Table of Contents (like section) will be translate into dutch. I thought that it would work with `babel` but it doesn't work and Latex doesn't give any error.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{PracWisk}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline - Section \thesection}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}



\title{ P }
\date[24 mei]{24 mei 2013\\
  Bachelorproject}
\author[]{S}
\institute[Gent]{$3$e Bachelor Wiskunde\\
  Gent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Schets}

\begin{frame}{\secname}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north},
  level distance=50pt]
  \Tree [. {a} [.{b} [.{\textit{c} \\ $d=e$} {\small f} ] ]  
                [.{g} [.{\textit{h}:\\ $i=j$} {\small k} ] ] ]                                                                                                            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[t]{\secname}
   \begin{figure}[h]
      \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{schroef}
      \caption{de}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame} 

\section{Definitie functionaal}

\subsection{Inleiding}

\begin{frame}[t]{\secname}{\subsecname}  
    \vspace{3mm} 
    Funct: p $\mapsto$ f \\ 
     \vspace{8mm}
    \textbf{V}: De booglengte\\
     \begin{equation*}
      f \mapsto j
     \end{equation*}

    \vspace{5mm}
     \uncover<2->{\textbf{Natuurkunde} $\rightarrow$ Speciale}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Lagrangedichtheid}

\begin{frame}[t]{\secname}{\subsecname}
  \uncover<1-4>{Fysisch}
    \vspace{5mm}
     \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{7pt}
        \item <2-4> Onafhankelijke
             \item <3-4> Veld
        \item[] <4> $\Rightarrow$ De velden
     \end{itemize}
     \vspace{-15mm}
    \uncover<5->{
     Lagrangedichtheid:
     \begin{eqnarray*}
         i = j       \end{eqnarray*}
     \vspace{5mm}
   \footnotesize{waarbij} $k = m$ \footnotesize{geldt.} }
\end{frame}

\subsection{Uiteindelijke gedaante}

\begin{frame}[c]{\secname}{\subsecname} 
  Gebrui\\

 \begin{block}{Fun}
    \textbf{Veronderstellingen}: 
     \begin{itemize}
       \item Domein
       \item gladde rand
     \end{itemize} 

     \vspace{5mm}
     \textbf{Definitie}:\\  
         \begin{equation*}
           J(\psi) = \int_{\Omega}{\mathcal{L}(\text{$x$, $\psi^{\alpha}(x)$, $\psi^{\alpha}_{x_{i}}(x)$)$dx$}}.   
       \end{equation*}
           $\psi$    
 \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you type `Section', then LaTeX will print "Section".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial user error.
